Apply theme color to mat-slide-toggle, Angular Material-18
I want to dynamically switch color for mat-slide-toggle. I have already created theme in angular mateiral-18, and it is working good for mat-button. But same class is not working for mat-slide-toggle.
 .alternate-theme-blue {
  @include mat.button-color(m3-blue-theme.$light-theme, $color-variant: primary);
  @include mat.slide-toggle-color(m3-blue-theme.$light-theme, $color-variant: primary);
}

<mat-slide-toggle                        
  [ngClass]="chosenThemeClass['asset-color-class']"
></mat-slide-toggle>

But above code not working in case of mat-slide-toggle, but same is working in case of mat-button.
Please help.
EDIT: my mat-slide-toggle doesn't looks like, angular-18. Not sure why.


remove the old prebuilt theme, @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; then it will look like the new theme, also use the same style css files as seen in my answer!

The solution or workaround to this problem is to use CSS Specificity, to ensure the styles get applied properly.
But you need to use two different classes, one for button and one for slide-toggle.
.alternate-theme-blue.mat-mdc-slide-toggle.mat-accent {
  @include mat.slide-toggle-color($theme, $color-variant: primary);
}

Stackblitz Demo

Coming to the actual problem, which is that a single class alternate-theme-blue alone like.
.alternate-theme-blue {
  @include mat.slide-toggle-color($theme, $color-variant: primary);
}

Is getting overridden by the default m3 styles of slide toggle.


@raju does this answer help you?
